# Registering test bean with same name in Spring Framework 5.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-framework-beans

I'm having following config in my production files:

```
@Configuration
internal class Config {

  @Bean
  fun clock() = Clock.systemUTC()
}
```

In tests:

```
@Configuration
class ClockTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  fun clock() = SetableClock()
}
```

My test annotations:

```
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
  classes = [
    MyApplication::class,
    ClockTestConfiguration::class
  ]
)
class MyTest {
...
```

When I was using Spring Boot `2.0.5.RELEASE` it worked like a charm. After upgrading to `2.1.0.RELEASE` it fails during bean registration.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'clock' defined in com.foo.clock.ClockTestConfiguration: 
Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=clockTestConfiguration; factoryMethodName=clock; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); 
defined in com.foo.clock.ClockTestConfiguration] for bean 'clock': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=config; factoryMethodName=clock; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/foo/clock/Config.class]] bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:894)
```

Is there a clean way to override such bean?

Comment: you can separate your configurations using profiles

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the `properties` attribute of `@SpringBootTest` to set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`.

Comment: Great solution. I wonder why this is not set to `true` by default when using `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: It isn't enabled by default as that could result in your tests all passing even though your application won't start due to a duplicate bean.